# Angular: meter en un interface una URL

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy creando un portfolio en el que cuando se hace clic en el + aparece un cuadro con las características del proyecto. En el interface recojo el título, la imagen y la descripción, todo ello como string. Pero querría meter información una información adicional de URL para redirigir al proyecto, pero no me sirve meterlo como string. ¿Hay algún modo de hacer esto con Angular?

interface.ts:

```
export interface IModal {

    title: string;
    image: string;
    description: string;
    
    
}
```

portfolio.component.ts:

```
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit{
items: Array<IModal> = [];
ngOnInit() {

this.items.push ({
  title: 'Web Personal',
  image: 'assets/img/portfolio1.jpg',
  description: 'Web desarrollada con Angular versión 12.'


});
```

Gracias.

Comment: Por qué no te sirve meterlo como string? una URL no es más que texto

Comment: Cierto sí, ya he visto la manera. Gracias.

Comment: de igual manera si desea usarlo con la interfaz URL de typescript pude hacerlo haciendo un new URL('http://www.example.com'). Y en la interfaz IModal se crea el nuevo campo de tipo URL